# Why order item quantity is not decreased after order placed

Tags: sales-order, cataloginventory, magento-1.9.3.3

I am facing a strange issue in our live site order item quantity is not decreased after order placed from the frontend.

(i.e) if a successful order has 5 products, 4 products quantity has been decreased successfully and remaining one product's inventory still same.

Since it's strange behavior looking forward to hearing for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system->configuration->catalog->Inventory` and **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** to **"yes"**

Like below image

[image]

Comment: Decrease Stock When Order is Placed is set to Yes already and the above-mentioned issue occurs in rare case. if an order has 5 products one or two product's quantity is not getting decreased.

Comment: @MuthukumarSivasamy please check this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5945

Comment: @MuthukumarSivasamy it may be store id  issue so please check

Comment: @MuthukumarSivasamy dont apply solutions directly on live site

Comment: We used to duplicate existing product to create a new product in our store also having this issue in our Magento 1.9.3.3